# SSIS Package web service task very slow

Tags: sql-server, wcf, ssis

I have an SSIS package which is using a web service task to call a WCF service. The service call takes between 200ms and 900ms when running it directly (C#, SoapUI, etc.) But when its called from the SSIS package it is consistently taking between 6 and 7 seconds. This is a big problem because the call is being made thousands of times and the package is taking ~8 hours to run.

I have verified the call is returning with the correct results. And have verified that calling the service from the database server with a c# program is fast.

Comment: Not familiar with the web service task, but if you already have the C# written to call the service, you can just plug that into a script component and test the difference.

Comment: If you look at the execution progress window, what percent of time is spent preparing for the call and what's the time to just run the call? Enabling the logging might give you some ideas.